How to Polyfill node core modules in webpack 5 for react
enter image description hereThis is the error coming
not able to Polyfill node core modules, I tried installing the necessary packages and also added the config-overrides.js file
After that i recieve these errors
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\webapp\node_modules\destroy'

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
